# SQLのクエリが冗長なので同じクエリを何回も書かないようにしたいです。

Tags: mysql

このままでも実行は可能ですが、同じクエリが見受けられるので冗長にならないようにするにはどうすれば良いですか？

試したことは、 `[my_goals] - [enemy_goals]` ですが[Unknown columns]になってしまいました。
バージョンは8.0.19です

```
SELECT
    p1.kickoff,
    c1.name AS my_country,
    c2.name AS enemy_country, 
    c1.ranking AS my_ranking,
    c2.ranking AS enemy_ranking,

    (SELECT COUNT(g1.id) FROM goals g1 WHERE p1.id = g1.pairing_id) AS my_goals,

    (
        SELECT COUNT(g2.id) 
        FROM goals g2 
        LEFT JOIN pairings p2 ON p2.id = g2.pairing_id
        WHERE p2.my_country_id = p1.enemy_country_id AND p2.enemy_country_id = p1.my_country_id
    ) AS enemy_goals,

    (SELECT COUNT(g1.id) FROM goals g1 WHERE p1.id = g1.pairing_id) - ( 
        SELECT COUNT(g2.id) 
        FROM goals g2 
        LEFT JOIN pairings p2 ON p2.id = g2.pairing_id
        WHERE p2.my_country_id = p1.enemy_country_id AND p2.enemy_country_id = p1.my_country_id
    ) AS goal_diff

FROM pairings p1
LEFT JOIN countries c1 ON c1.id = p1.my_country_id
LEFT JOIN countries c2 ON c2.id = p1.enemy_country_id
WHERE c1.group_name = 'C' AND c2.group_name = 'C'
ORDER BY p1.kickoff, c1.ranking
```

[このリンク先の正解の部分のコードです](https://tech.pjin.jp/blog/2016/08/26/sql%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%92%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C-%E5%95%8F17/)

> #### 問題：問題16の結果に得失点差を追加してください。
>
> 表示するカラム
>   ・キックオフ日時
>   ・自国名
>   ・対戦相手国名
>   ・自国FIFAランク
>   ・対戦相手国FIFAランク
>   ・自国のゴール数
>   ・対戦国のゴール数
>   ・得失点差（※追加！）
>
> ソート順
>   ・キックオフ日時
>   ・自国FIFAランク
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: お使いのMySQLのバージョンは何ですか。

Comment: [こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66070) をしたのと同じ人でしょうか？ / もしアカウントが複数に分かれてしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にマージすることを検討してください。 - [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)